# Abstracting a function doesn't make it reusable; info is kept from previous call

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache-kafka

I have to use the code below several times through out my project. I have therefore decided to abstract it into a `utils` file. Therefore when ever I need it all I have to do is call `consumer("topic")`. How ever for some reason it doesn't allow me to re-use the function and it just keeps the info from the previous call.

```
var async = require('async')
var kafka = require('kafka-node'),
    Consumer = kafka.Consumer,
    client = new kafka.KafkaClient({ kafkaHost: 'kafka:9092' }),
    offset = new kafka.Offset(client)

let messages = []
let latestOffset
let consumerInstance

let consumer = async (topic) => {
    messages = []
    latestOffset = 0
    consumerInstance = ""

    offset.fetch([{ topic: topic, partition: 0, time: -1 }], (errd, data) => {
        if (data) {
            latestOffset = data[topic][0][0];
        }
    });

    consumerInstance = new Consumer(client, [{ topic: topic, partition: 0, fromOffset: latestOffset }], { autoCommit: true });
    let KafkaConsumer = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        consumerInstance.on('message', async (message) => {
            consumerInstance.pause()
            await q.push(message, function (err) {
                if (err) { reject(err); return }
                else {
                    consumerInstance.resume()
                }
            })
            if (message.offset == (message.highWaterOffset - 1)) {
                resolve()
            }
        })
        consumerInstance.on('error', async (err) => {
            reject(err)
        })
    })

    await KafkaConsumer

    await q.drain()

    return messages

}

var q = async.queue(async (message, cb) => {
    await processTestCase(message, cb)
}, 1)

q.drain(async function () {
    // Pause the consumer
    consumerInstance.close(true, function (err, message) {
    });
});

processTestCase = async (message, cb) => {    
    messages.push(JSON.parse(message.value))
    cb()
}

module.exports = { consumer }
```

The main issue is that unless I use a `let` in front of the `consumerInstance` I cant seem to reuse the function, how ever when I do that, I cant close the consumer in the `q.drain`
Any clues or pointers are very welcomed. TIA!

Comment: Because it's async, if you have two calls happening at once, they'll both end up returning the last array you assigned to `messages`, because it's a shared variable. Declare your variable inside the function.

Comment: That is a good point I have polished. However the issue arises when im not able to reuse  the consumer instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be seeing repeat messages because your `messages` array is in the same **scope** as your export. That means if you call `consumer('topic')` concurrently at any point, those calls would be sharing the same reference to `messages`. That means setting `messages = []` from one consumer call would affect the other messages of the other consumer calls as well. You do not want that.

Here is my refactor. I swapped out `async` for a Promise library I created. I tried to do everything you wanted. One thing I am unsure about is `message.highWaterOffset`. There is more work to be done if you run across a memory leak there.

```js
var { pipe, get } = require('rubico')
var kafka = require('kafka-node'),
    Consumer = kafka.Consumer

// safely accesses properties with get
const safeParseTopic = (topic, data) => get([topic, 0, 0])(data)

// changed this to return a Promise
const fetchLatestOffset = client => topic => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  new kafka.Offset(client).fetch(
    [{ topic: topic, partition: 0, time: -1 }],
    (err, data) => err ? reject(err) : resolve(safeParseTopic(topic, data)),
  )
})

// it's recommend to create new client for different consumers
// https://www.npmjs.com/package/kafka-node#consumer
const makeConsumerInstance = client => ({ topic, offset }) => new Consumer(
  client,
  [{ topic, offset, partition: 0 }],
  { autoCommit: true },
)

// this is the function version of KafkaConsumer from your example
// consume(consumerInstance) == KafkaConsumer
const consume = consumerInstance => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const messages = []

  consumerInstance.on('message', message => {
    messages.push(message)
    // you don't need to pause and resume
    // you are gauranteed one message at a time in this block
    if (message.offset == (message.highWaterOffset - 1)) {
      resolve(messages)
      // you have to handle cleanup of consumerInstance after the resolve
      // If there's a memory leak, I would look here
    }
  })

  // handles a termination signal from the producer
  consumerInstance.on('end', () => resolve(messages))

  consumerInstance.on('error', reject)
})

// topic -> messages
// pipe chains async functions together
const consumer = topic => {
  const client = new kafka.KafkaClient({ kafkaHost: 'kafka:9092' })
  return pipe([
    fetchLatestOffset(client), // topic -> latestOffset

    latestOffset => ({
      topic: topic,
      offset: latestOffset,
    }), // latestOffset -> ({ topic, offset })

    makeConsumerInstance(client), // ({ topic, offset }) -> consumerInstance

    consume, // consumerInstance -> messages
  ])(topic)
}

module.exports = { consumer }
```

Comment: This seems to work like a charm, that being said, offset requires a client to be retrieved. 
I added the client just on top just like in the original code, but that seems to defeat the point, of your solution. Any pointer oon how to fix that?

Comment: client is created in `makeConsumerInstance`, first line. Docs example assumes only one consumer, so it's a bit different than what you need

Comment: Yep, agreed, how ever in your example you're using the value of offset, set at the top, to instantiate a new instance for the consumer. However offset requires a client to be retrieved. if you dont provide a client, you get the error client is not defined.

Comment: that offset is different, it is not used and instead this one is `(topic, offset) => new Consumer(`. That said, linters usually complain about what I am currently doing in my example so I will edit the variable name for clarity

Comment: Line 4 thrws the error: 
`ReferenceError: client is not defined`

Comment: refactored: one client per consumer as per docs recommendation